# I AM authorisation error while creating a table in CBT tool

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to create a table in cbt tool, it is giving me error attached, I have checked the permissions and set it to owner and bigtable admin, it is still rendering the same error, I have also enabled Bigtable API but same error persists. I am trying this in GCP trail account in the Shell internal terminal. Appreciate your help.enter image description here

[enter image description here][[image: []][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fTPl.png)1]

Comment: The exact error is as follows: 
Creating table: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Access denied. Missing IAM permission: bigtable.tables.create.

Comment: I got the same IAM error following the [cbt quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/quickstart-cbt). I only gave my service account the "Bigtable Administrator" role though. I eventually got around it by just using the "Owner" role. I know it's not best practice, but for the sake of learning how cbt works, I thought it was fine.

Answer (score 1):

To use the CBT tool, you'll need to make sure you have a few variables set correctly. First is [GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the path of a JSON file that contains your service account key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started)

Then you'll need to make sure your .cbtrc (CBT configuration file) has your project and instance id set and that those variables match the service account key that you specified above. You can set those variables with these commands

```
   echo project = project-id > ~/.cbtrc
   echo instance = quickstart-instance >> ~/.cbtrc
```

And your final .cbtrc file should look like this:

```
project = project-id
instance = quickstart-instance
```

I'd recommend to check out the [Bigtable CBT Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/quickstart-cbt?hl=en), to make sure you follow all the steps there if you still have this issue.